# Are there any good blackberry web development tools?

Tags: blackberry

I'm trying to debug a javascript error on a Backberry Curve 9700. I get no error messages but something obviously doesn't work. I've been trying to download the blackberry simulator in hopes it can give me some more output but it's download keeps dying before its done. I also can't find any docs confirming it has better output then the device itself.

How should one go about properly developing and debugging webapps for the blackberry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RIM made an open source project for what you need: https://github.com/blackberry/WebWorks

Answer (score 1):

following urls can guide you that how to start web development

[go through developers zone](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/browserdev/opensource.jsp)